# to convert dictionary values to keys in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, data-structures, key

The groups_per_user function receives a dictionary, which contains group names with the list of users. Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a dictionary with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for key,values in group_dictionary.items():
        for users in values:
            user_groups[users] = user_groups.get(users,0)+1
    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],"public":  ["admin", "userB"],"administrator":         ["admin"] }))
# output must be {'admin':["local","public","administrator"],'userA':"local" ,'userB':"public"}
#output I am getting {'admin': 3, 'userA': 1, 'userB': 1}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: Input is strings and output is strings. I'm not sure why you used arithmetics  `.get(..., 0) + 1` and expected the output to *not* contain numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the current `dict` and reverse the key-value pairs:

```
d = {"local": ["admin", "userA"], "public":  ["admin", "userB"], "administrator": ["admin"] }

res = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for e in v:
        if e in res:
            res[e].append(k)
        else:
            res[e] = [k]
print(res)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'admin': ['public', 'administrator', 'local'], 'userB': ['public'], 'userA': ['local']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below program. it just iterates through all the elements of group_dictionary and constructs user_dictionary.

```py
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups=dict([(a,[]) for a in sum(group_dictionary.values(),list())])
    for u in user_groups:
        for g in group_dictionary:
            if u in group_dictionary[g]:
                user_groups[u].append(g)
    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],"public":  ["admin", "userB"],"administrator":         ["admin"] }))
```

**Output**

```
{'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Comment: user_groups=dict([(a,[]) for a in sum(group_dictionary.values(),list())])  i did not understand this line can please explain why u used this

Comment: This initiates `user_groups` dictionary with username and empty list pairs.